# Obtaining the most reoccurring attribute in SQL

Tags: sql

Using SQL, I have a table with a list of usernames and I am trying to output the most repeated one with out using MAX. I am very new to SQL so any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the aggregate function `count()` to get the total number of times a `username` is repeated:

```
select username, count(username) Total
from yourtable
group by username
order by total desc
```

Then depending on your database you can return the username that appears the most.

In MySQL, you can use `LIMIT`:

```
select username, count(username) Total
from yourtable
group by username
order by total desc
limit 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e9db/1)

In SQL Server, you can use `TOP`:

```
select TOP 1 with Ties username, count(username) Total
from yourtable
group by username
order by total desc
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f03d/1)

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for your response, Much appreciated. I'm sorry I should have been more clear, I need the top OR top(s) responses. 

For example -

USERNAMES-

Dave
Jim
Dave
Tom
Dave
Jim
Frank
Jim

I would need to output both Dave and Jim. Sorry If I am being unclear, I'm new to this.

Thanks

Dave

Comment: @Daviepark The version using `TOP` should work if you are using SQL Server -- see this demo with your sample data -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23571/2